# MongoDB Limit By Condition

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongo collection that contains questions each with their own difficulty.

What I want to do is query the collection based on the amount configured for each questions difficulty.

So say I have three difficulty levels, 1(easy, 2(medium), 3(hard) and I have configured my application to pull 15 easy, 15 medium, and 20 hard for a total of 50 questions.

What would be the best way to aggregate this data? So far I have no luck with `$match` or `$cond` and cannot seem to conditionally limit the `$in` operator as well.

Comment: Please add what you've tried to the post and also add sample documents for testing.

Comment: What I've tried isn't relevant as you cannot use `$match($in...$limit)` for mongo which is what I was hoping for. The documents for testing can be arbitrary, can just have documents with the key `difficulty` and values ranging from 1-3, e.g `{"difficuty": Number(1)}`, however I don't really see that as pertinent information either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's consider you have following document structure

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5845ad672324699ec94a5399"), "difficulty" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5845ad692324699ec94a539a"), "difficulty" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5845ad6b2324699ec94a539b"), "difficulty" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5845ad6c2324699ec94a539c"), "difficulty" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5845ad702324699ec94a539d"), "difficulty" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5845ad722324699ec94a539e"), "difficulty" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5845ad732324699ec94a539f"), "difficulty" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5845ad742324699ec94a53a0"), "difficulty" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5845ad762324699ec94a53a1"), "difficulty" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5845ad762324699ec94a53a2"), "difficulty" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5845ad782324699ec94a53a3"), "difficulty" : 3 }
```

Now you want to pull `15 easy, 15 medium, and 20 hard for a total of 50 questions` so for this first should create group on `difficulty` and use `$cond` in `project` to `slice` array according to your counts. Check below query:

```
db.difficulty.aggregate({ "$match": { "difficulty": { "$in": [1, 2, 3] } } }, 
        { "$group": { "_id": "$difficulty", "data": { "$push": "$$ROOT" } } }, {
    "$project": {
        "result": {
            "$cond": {
                "if": { "$eq": [1, "$_id"] },
                "then": { "easy": { "$slice": ["$data", 15] } }, //15 for easy
                "else": {
                    "$cond": {
                        "if": { "$eq": [2, "$_id"] },
                        "then": { "medium": { "$slice": ["$data", 15] } },// 15 for medium
                        "else": { "hard": { "$slice": ["$data", 20] } } // 20 for hard
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}).pretty()
```

Comment: I'm getting an error with this regarding a missing 'else', when I add an empty condition it's given 0 results, so I'm currently trying to imrpove the final condition to see if that's why my result set is empty. Error is: 
`assert: command failed: { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "Missing 'else' parameter to $cond", "code" : 17082 } : aggregate failed`

Comment: you forgot some brackets, correct syntax is db.difficulty.aggregate([{$match:...}])

Comment: Great, while this doesn't combine all the results into one dataset, it still has the records I want! thanks a lot!